# How can I play audio in the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

need some help here. I'm new to unity. I'm creating a game based on rocket ships and have attached an audio file to my rocket ship. Even wrote the code to make it play when I press a particular button.

Up until yesterday, it seemed to work just fine, but for some reason, today the audio no longer plays when I play the game. I have read articles and watched videos but none seemed to help.

I've tried several things, from de-attaching and re-attaching the audio file to rewriting the code.

```
public AudioSource audioSource;

public void Thrust() 
{
    float rotationThisFrame = rcsThrust * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) 
    {
        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * rotationThisFrame);

        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
            audioSource.Play();

        else
            audioSource.Stop();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing

```
if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
    audioSource.Play();
else
    audioSource.Stop();
```

so if the `audioSource` is playing you do `Stop` it! You basically are alterntely turning the sound on and off **every frame** so you always only "hear" the sound for one single frame and then it is started from the beginning of the audiofile.

---

You probably ment to add the `else` case rather to your surrounding check for the key like

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) 
{
    rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * rotationThisFrame);

    if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        audioSource.Play();
}
else
{
    audioSource.Stop();
}
```

Assuming ofcourse the `audioSource` is reference and the `clip` set it now should `Play` the sound while holding the <kbd>W</kbd> key, and `Stop` when not holding the <kbd>W</kbd> key.